# How to hide Post except below the Title on Homepage Thumbnail?

Tags: wordpress

My Website is https://new4kmovies.com

I want to hide the Post except on homepage, i want to keep the thumbnail and title only and want to remove rest.

Can i do it using custom css? I am using " The Box" wordpress theme.

Thanks
Salena

Answer (score 0):

Try following on your style.css

```
.home .grid2-sidebar .entry-summary {
    display: none !important;
}
```